# How to add File[] files with specific order

Tags: java, file

I have small problem with textfilter. Here's my code:

```
File f = new File("c:\\dir\\");
    FilenameFilter textFilter = new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {

            if (name.toLowerCase().startsWith("a")
                    && name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt")) {
                return true;
            } else if ((name.toLowerCase().startsWith("b") && name
                    .toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt"))) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    };

    File[] files = f.listFiles(textFilter);
```

Now the order in "files" array look's like:

> A  B

How can I change the order of "files" array that could look's like:

> B A

Why I must do that? Becaues I need first read file "B" over the file "A". Could somebody write me any sugestions? Thanks.

Comment: Do a sorting of the files based on the name.

Comment: I know. But could you give me a example of that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is:

```
Arrays.sort(files, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Thanks @Gofoboso